# Exporting link from google sheet via google drive api

Tags: python, google-sheets

Is there any way to export link to published sheet (e.g pic below) via google drive api in python?[image: linkpublishedsheet]

Script code from google drive api tutorial.m

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_api_request():
    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return redirect('authorize')
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(**session['credentials'])
    drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
    files = drive.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'").execute().get('items', [])
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        print(" ")  
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    res = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11W_MaQm6UCMhufuKQCcXYw10ggkTyzz_mOsvGOgOXN0/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv')
    return(res.content)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true')
    session['state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    state = session['state']
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    return redirect(url_for('test_api_request'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the URL in your question, it might be the URL of the web published spreadsheet. If my understanding is not wrong, unfortunately, the URL cannot be directly retrieved by Drive API and other APIs. But the same link can be created using file ID of spreadsheet. If you can retrieve the file ID, could you please try the following URL? You can select one of them.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=### fileId ###
```

or

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### fileId ###/pubhtml
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your solution kinda works . Yeah I can download csv (I wrote `pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv` instead of `/pubhtml`) when I write this into google but in code when I use pandas.read_csv it returns google page to login instead of csv file and that is very odd because I am already logged in.

Comment: @Mr Lukas I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. When the spreadsheet is published, the sheet can be retrieved without the access token and log in process. So can I ask you about your script?

Comment: o yeah sure. This code is from google drive api tutorial.

Comment: @Mr Lukas Thank you for updating it. In my environment, the values retrieved by ``requests.get()`` is CSV. But if the spreadsheet was not published, the login screen was displayed. So can you confirm about it again?

Comment: Yeah you are right it works! I do not know why previously I had login screen but It  does not matter now. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Mr Lukas Than you for your reply. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.